# Jquery Traversing - Seleccionar "Alrededores"

Tags: jquery

Buenas. Quiero a partir del `.elemento_seleccionado`:

```
<table border="1">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Col1</th>
            <th>Col2</th>
            <th>Col3</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td>Iz/Ar</td>
            <td class='arriba'>Arriba</td>
            <td>De/Ar</td>
        </tr>                                                   
        <tr>
            <td>Izquierda</td>
            <td class='elemento_seleccionado>Seleccion</td>
            <td>Derecha</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Iz/Aba</td>
            <td>Abajo</td>
            <td>De/Aba</td>
        </tr>                       
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Poder seleccionar su:

1. Elemento Arriba
2. Elemento Abajo
3. Diagonales

Por ahora he podido realizar la seleccion de:

1. Izquierda

   $(".elemento_seleccionado").prev().css("background","cyan");
2. Derecha

   $(".elemento_seleccionado").next().css("background","orange");

Answer (score 2, accepted):

De la siguiente manera podes seleccionar todas las posiciones, borra las que no necesites:

***EDITADO***

Para que haga la selección no importa cuantas columnas o filas tenga

```js
var index = $(".elemento_seleccionado").parent().find('td').index($(".elemento_seleccionado"));

$(".elemento_seleccionado").parent().prev().find("td:eq("+(index-1)+")").css("background","cyan");//Iz/Ar
$(".elemento_seleccionado").parent().prev().find("td:eq("+index+")").css("background","cyan");//Arriba
$(".elemento_seleccionado").parent().prev().find("td:eq("+(index+1)+")").css("background","cyan");// De/Ar
$(".elemento_seleccionado").prev().css("background","cyan");//Izquierda
$(".elemento_seleccionado").next().css("background","cyan");//Derecha
$(".elemento_seleccionado").parent().next().find("td:eq("+(index-1)+")").css("background","cyan");//Iz/Aba 
$(".elemento_seleccionado").parent().next().find("td:eq("+index+")").css("background","cyan");//Abajo 
$(".elemento_seleccionado").parent().next().find("td:eq("+(index+1)+")").css("background","cyan");//De/Aba
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<table border="1">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Col1</th>
            <th>Col2</th>
            <th>Col3</th>
            <th>Col4</th>
            <th>Col5</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td>x</td>
            <td>Iz/Ar</td>
            <td class='arriba'>Arriba</td>
            <td>De/Ar</td>
            <td>x</td>
            <td>x</td>
        </tr>                                                   
        <tr>
            <td>x</td>
            <td>Izquierda</td>
            <td class='elemento_seleccionado'>Seleccion</td>
            <td>Derecha</td>
            <td>x</td>
            <td>x</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>x</td>
            <td>Iz/Aba</td>
            <td>Abajo</td>
            <td>De/Aba</td>
            <td>x</td>
            <td>x</td>
        </tr>                       
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: Hola. Y que pasa si a la tabla se le agregan x cantidad de filas nuevas? Ese es mi punto. Ya no serviría

Comment: si, no serviria en ese caso, pero eso no era parte del problema que planteaste en la pregunta.

Comment: Ya esta editado para que lo planteaste en el comentario.

Comment: De todas maneras la otra respuesta tiene lo que necesitas. Saludos!

Answer (score 4):

Puedes sacar las celdas de la fila actual y obtener el índice de la celda seleccionada a través del método `index`. A partir de ahí se puede calcular los índices de las celdas a seleccionar en las filas anteriores y siguientes.

Este ejemplo selecciona las celdas alrededor de la celda sobre la que se hace click:

```js
$(function(){
  $('td').click(function(){
    $('td').css('backgroundColor', 'white');
    var $selected= $(this);
    var index = $selected.parent().find('td').index($selected);
    
    $selected.css('backgroundColor', 'blue');
    $selected.prev().css('backgroundColor', 'green');
    $selected.next().css('backgroundColor', 'green');
    $selected.parent().prev()
    .find('td:eq(' + Math.max(index-1, 0) + ')'
      + ', td:eq(' + index + ')'
      + ', td:eq(' + (index + 1) + ')')
    .css('backgroundColor', 'green');
    $selected.parent().next()
    .find('td:eq(' + Math.max(index-1, 0) + ')'
      + ', td:eq(' + index + ')'
      + ', td:eq(' + (index + 1) + ')')
    .css('backgroundColor', 'green');
  });
});
```

```css
td{
  border: solid 1px #666666;
  padding: 10px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
  <tr><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td></tr>
  <tr><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td></tr>
  <tr><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td></tr>
  <tr><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td></tr>
  <tr><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td></tr>
  <tr><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td></tr>
</table>
```